# python h5py: appending additional datasets to existing h5 file

Tags: python, h5py

I have the following sample code to append a new dataset to existing .h5 file.

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

file1 = 'sampleFile.h5'
fileIn = h5py.File(file1,'a')
fileIn.create_dataset('addedDataset', (100,1), dtype='i8', data = [0]*100)
```

However, I can't event open the h5 file in 'append' mode to begin with.
I get the following error:

```
IOError: Unable to create file (Unable to open file: name = 'sampleFile.h5', errno = 17, error message = 'file exists', flags = 15, o_flags = c2)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Its working on my system, please try to update your packages maybe there's some issue. Same code works.

Comment: @SnehalParmar Did you try on the existing h5 file?

Comment: yeah its working on existing file too, no issues i have faced to run it.

Comment: @SnehalParmar thanks.. it didn't work for me, and I got around it by using 'r+' instead..